Datadog Integration with Azure App Service doesnt work
Summary of problem
I have a django application which is containerised and running on Azure app service and I am having trouble sending traces to datadog.
I have been stuck on this issue for a while and cant seem to solve it
2024-08-30T07:45:27.7503477Z failed to send, dropping 1 traces to intake at http://127.0.0.1:8126/v0.5/traces after 3 retries, 1 additional messages skipped
2024-08-30T07:45:33.5918905Z failed to send, dropping 1 traces to intake at http://127.0.0.1:8126/v0.5/traces after 3 retries
2024-08-30T07:45:46.1090952Z failed to send, dropping 1 traces to intake at http://127.0.0.1:8126/v0.5/traces after 3 retries
2024-08-30T07:46:08.9280102Z failed to send, dropping 1 traces to intake at http://127.0.0.1:8126/v0.5/traces after 3 retries
2024-08-30T07:46:12.7362637Z failed to send, dropping 1 traces to intake at http://127.0.0.1:8126/v0.5/traces after 3 retries
2024-08-30T07:46:20.2283515Z failed to send, dropping 2 traces to intake at http://127.0.0.1:8126/v0.5/traces after 3 retries
2024-08-30T07:47:03.2944981Z failed to send, dropping 1 traces to intake at http://127.0.0.1:8126/v0.5/traces after 3 retries, 3 additional messages skipped
2024-08-30T07:47:13.1601344Z failed to send, dropping 1 traces to intake at http://127.0.0.1:8126/v0.5/traces after 3 retries, 4 additional messages skipped
2024-08-30T07:48:02.5895355Z failed to send, dropping 1 traces to intake at http://127.0.0.1:8126/v0.5/traces after 3 retries, 2 additional messages skipped
2024-08-30T07:48:04.6799632Z failed to send, dropping 1 traces to intake at http://127.0.0.1:8126/v0.5/traces after 3 retries, 9 additional messages skipped
2024-08-30T07:48:05.5915341Z 2024-08-30 07:48:05 UTC | CORE | INFO | (pkg/serializer/serializer.go:508 in SendProcessesMetadata) | Sent processes metadata payload, size: 296 bytes.
2024-08-30T07:48:10.4490358Z failed to send, dropping 1 traces to intake at http://127.0.0.1:8126/v0.5/traces after 3 retries, 3 additional messages skipped
2024-08-30T07:49:00.9732551Z failed to send, dropping 1 traces to intake at http://127.0.0.1:8126/v0.5/traces after 3 retries, 11 additional messages skipped
2024-08-30T07:49:06.7247474Z failed to send, dropping 1 traces to intake at http://127.0.0.1:8126/v0.5/traces after 3 retries, 4 additional messages skipped
2024-08-30T07:49:00.1989114Z failed to send, dropping 1 traces to intake at http://127.0.0.1:8126/v0.5/traces after 3 retries, 9 additional messages skipped
2024-08-30T07:48:23.764824438Z failed to send, dropping 4 traces to intake at http://127.0.0.1:8126/v0.5/traces after 3 retries, 2 additional messages skipped
2024-08-30T07:48:27.846468571Z 2024-08-30 07:48:27 UTC | CORE | INFO | (pkg/serializer/serializer.go:508 in SendProcessesMetadata) | Sent processes metadata payload, size: 297 bytes.
2024-08-30T07:49:02.546460960Z failed to send, dropping 1 traces to intake at http://127.0.0.1:8126/v0.5/traces after 3 retries, 6 additional messages skipped
2024-08-30T07:49:04.667388902Z failed to send, dropping 1 traces to intake at http://127.0.0.1:8126/v0.5/traces after 3 retries
2024-08-30T07:49:14.2128173Z failed to send, dropping 1 traces to intake at http://127.0.0.1:8126/v0.5/traces after 3 retries
2024-08-30T07:49:12.730441668Z failed to send, dropping 1 traces to intake at http://127.0.0.1:8126/v0.5/traces after 3 retries, 11 additional messages skipped
2024-08-30T07:49:17.7142847Z failed to send, dropping 1 traces to intake at http://127.0.0.1:8126/v0.5/traces after 3 retries, 4 additional messages skipped

Here is my Docker File
FROM node:lts AS frontend
ARG SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN
ARG DATADOG_API_KEY

WORKDIR /app/frontend
RUN npm install -g pnpm

COPY frontend/package.json .
COPY frontend/pnpm-lock.yaml .
RUN pnpm install

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

WORKDIR /app/frontend
RUN  pnpm run build 

FROM python:3.11

ARG DATADOG_API_KEY
ENV DATADOG_API_KEY=$DATADOG_API_KEY

RUN DD_AGENT_MAJOR_VERSION=7 DD_API_KEY=$DATADOG_API_KEY DD_HOSTNAME=app_name DD_SITE="datadoghq.eu" DD_APM_ENABLED=true bash -c "$(curl -L https://s3.amazonaws.com/dd-agent/scripts/install_script.sh)"

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install gunicorn
COPY backend/requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY backend/ .
COPY frontend/public ./app_name/static
COPY --from=frontend /app/backend/app_name/dist ./app_name/dist

RUN python manage.py collectstatic --noinput

CMD [ "/app/entrypoint.sh" ]


entrypoint.sh
#!/bin/bash

python manage.py migrate --noinput

DD_AGENT_MAJOR_VERSION=7 DD_API_KEY=$DATADOG_API_KEY DD_HOSTNAME=app_name DD_APM_ENABLED=true DD_SITE="datadoghq.eu" /opt/datadog-agent/bin/agent/agent run &

case $1 in
    "runserver")
        gunicorn server.wsgi --bind=0.0.0.0:8000 --workers 4 --timeout 900
        ;;
    "process_tasks")
        gunicorn server.wsgi --bind=0.0.0.0:8000 --workers 4 --timeout 900 &
        python manage.py process_tasks
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Invalid command '$1'"
        exit 1
esac


I have verified if the datadog agent is running
I can't seem to understand why traces are not being sent and no service is being registered
Django settings.py
# DATA_DOG
ddtrace.tracer.configure(
    hostname='127.0.0.1',
    port=8126,
)

ENVIRONMENT = os.getenv('ENVIRONMENT', 'development')
SERVICE_NAME = {
    'development': 'local_django_dev_server',
    'staging': 'staging_django_server',
    'production': 'production_django_api_server',
}.get(ENVIRONMENT, 'local_django_dev_server')

ddtrace.config.django['service_name'] = SERVICE_NAME

patch_all()

DATADOG_API_KEY = os.getenv('DATADOG_API_KEY')


DATADOG_CONFIG = {
    'api_key': DATADOG_API_KEY,
    'app_name': f"app-{ENVIRONMENT.lower()}-tech",
    'env': ENVIRONMENT
}

Which version of dd-trace-py are you using?
ddtrace==2.11.0
